# How can I change the text on the diagonals of the scatter plots produced by the "pairs" function?

Tags: r, plot

I want to change the text on the diagonals produced by the following code in R (I want to change the text showing Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length and Petal.Width).

[image: Graph produced by the code below]

I've tried inserting something for the diag.panel argument in the "pairs" function, but have had no luck with that.

```
#Extracts the iris species column from the iris dataset
iris_class = iris$Species

#Change the class from characters to numerical values for indexing
# #1 = Iris-setosa
# #2 = Iris-versicolor
# #3 = Iris-virginica
class_to_number = as.numeric(factor(iris_class))


#A function to show the linear regression line in each graph
upper_panel_regression_line = function(x,y, ...){
  points(x,y,...)
  linear_regression = lm(y~x)
  linear_regression_line = abline(linear_regression)
}

#A function to calculate and show the R-squared value of each panel
lower_panel_r_squared = function(x, y, ...){
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(0, 2, 0, 2))
  r = cor(x, y)
  r_squared = round(r^2, digits = 2)
  text_of_r_squared = paste0("R-squared = ", r_squared)
  text(1, 1, text_of_r_squared)
}


pairs(iris[1:4], main = "Predicting Iris Class", 
lower.panel=lower_panel_r_squared, upper.panel = 
        upper_panel_regression_line, col=c("red","blue","green") [class_to_number])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty close to @Axeman, but I thought a more programmatic way of assigning new labels would help.

First, as always, you can just change the column names of the data going in, with `colnames` or `setNames` or just `names`. I'm assuming this is not the solution you want.

Using the `text.panel=` argument is a little troublesome in that it must be pre-defined to "know" what the labels should be, either by comparing with the old labels or by knowing the position. Instead of trying to be uber fancy, I suggest a slight-fancy way of doing it.

As you can see in @Axeman's answer (and in the documentation for `?pairs`), normally `text.panel=` and other arguments take a function, but no arguments to that function are user-controllable, so we'll define a function that takes first the new labels to use, then returns a function that is handed to `pairs`.

```r
my.text.panel <- function(labels) {
  function(x, y, lbl, ...) {
    if (lbl %in% names(labels)) lbl <- labels[[lbl]]
    text(x, y, lbl, ...)
  }
}

pairs(iris[1:4], main = "Predicting Iris Class", 
      text.panel = my.text.panel(c(Sepal.Length="Slen", Sepal.Width="Swid",
                                   Petal.Length="Plen", Petal.Width="Pwid")),
      lower.panel = lower_panel_r_squared,
      upper.panel = upper_panel_regression_line,
      col=c("red","blue","green") [class_to_number])
```

With this function, you can specify all, some, or none of the labels; the default here is to use the previous label if a new mapping is not found, but that could easily be extended in the function to control other methods.

The result:

[image: updated pairs plot, new diagonal labels]

I originally kept the `mean(x)` and such from @Axeman's answer, but since the otherwise default behavior (using an internally-defined function named `textPanel`) seems to expect single numbers and not vectors, I believe `mean` is unnecessary (though not problematic).

Comment: Ah yes, this is much nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
diag_custom_labels <- function(x, y, labels, cex, font, ...) {
  if (!exists('i')) i <<- 1
  text(mean(x), mean(y), c('my', 'custom', 'diag', 'labels')[[i]], cex = cex)
  i <<- i + 1
}

pairs(iris[1:4], main = "Predicting Iris Class", 
      lower.panel=lower_panel_r_squared, upper.panel = upper_panel_regression_line, 
      text.panel = diag_custom_labels,
      col=c("red","blue","green") [class_to_number])
```

[image]